# How to preserve a certain form of numbers in an array in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, formatting

I have a a table of values, which list item ids by the amount of those items in different qualities, like so:

```
ID      QB      QC      UI
006780  12      -       6
100780  48      15      8
```

And so on for a thousand rows. As part of a further wrangling effort, I wish to get the id's and move them elsewhere and position them under each other with 2 blank cells between them. This is the code I've come up with and please bear with me, I'm trying to lear:

```
Sub laatuJako()

Dim idRange As Range
Dim tyoWb As Workbook
Dim tyoWks As Worksheet
Dim idRivit As Integer
Dim idArray() As Variant 

Set tyoWb = ThisWorkbook
Set tyoWks = tyoWb.Sheets("Pivots->Apu")
idRivit = tyoWks.Range("Q7").End(xlDown).Row
ReDim idArray(0)
Dim varCounter As Integer
varCounter = 0
```

This next loop is a way I could form the array, since it seemed to run into run-time error 9 in the next loop.

```
For i = 0 To idRivit - 1
    tyoWks.Activate
    idArray(i) = tyoWks.Range("Q" & 7 + i).Value
    varCounter = varCounter + 1
    ReDim Preserve idArray(varCounter)

Next i

Dim k As Integer
Dim j As Integer
k = 0
j = 0
Do While k < idRivit

    tyoWks.Range("X" & 7 + j).Value = idArray(k)

    j = j + 3
    k = k + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Now  the code works, but it seems that (un)helpfully VBA changed the id attribute to a number and printed the ids with numbers in front of them, for example 006780 as 6780. This was not wanted and so I changed the array into a string array, but it made no difference. Now an array is not necessary here and I can just copy-paste them directly using a loop, but I want to understand how I can control something like this, since the issue will come up again in situations where an array would be preferable.

Apologies, if the question is poorly described, there is a first time for everything.

Comment: Set the cell format to text before adding the id attribute

Comment: You are saving the ids as `Integer`s, right? That will of course treat them as a number without leading zeros. This is just fine as long as the amount of ciphers does not alter (all ids have the same length). Then you could adjust the formatting of the cells for ids to have leading zeros if the length is less than the fixed id length.

Comment: Thank you! Both answers work. I had a sneaking suspicion the problem was something like this, instead of the array.